# Update a field with the result of another query

Tags: ms-access

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW 
    tblOrderItems.OrderID, 
    SUM(tblOrderItems.LinePrice) AS result
FROM 
    tblOrderItems
GROUP BY 
    tblOrderItems.OrderID;
```

I currently have this query set up to give me the total price of an order. I want to update the column `tblOrder.TotalCost` in another table, `tblOrder` with the result of this query. I can provide additional details as necessary.

Comment: Given that query which gives you `result` whenever you need to see it, what is the point of storing it into `tblOrder`?

Comment: It's used in that table for other calculations and as part of displaying it to the user. Pretty much just for convenience and it's part of my assignment.

Comment: Does `tblOrder` have an `OrderID` field?  Is that field numeric datatype in both tables?

Comment: Yes, the OrderID is present and autonumber in both tables.

Comment: Good.  An Access `UPDATE` based on a `GROUP BY` will be treated as "not updateable".  Ordinarily I would suggest you consider a [DSum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193998.aspx) expression for your `UPDATE`, but have no idea whether that is acceptable for your assignment.

Comment: So what layout should I write the update query in?

Comment: `GROUP BY tblOrderItems.OrderID` forces the result set to only distinct *OrderID*s, so `DISTINCTROW` is unnecessary.